# How generic is the {} construction syntax?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11, language-lawyer, curly-braces

In a [talk about initialization lists](http://youtu.be/-OioZ78jnlM), I understood Stroustrup basically saying that the new construction syntax with curly braces is *supposed* to be a general replacement for all the previous construction syntaxes:

```
X x1(); // most vexing parse ... doesn't work as intended
X x2(x1);
X x3 = x1;
X x4 = X();
```

Instead, the new syntax is supposed to be used uniformly as a possible replacement that you can use in *every* situation ... again, that's the core message that I took from his talk. Maybe I misunderstood him.

So, the question is, how generic is this syntax? **Is it possible to never use old-style construction in new C++11 code or are there situations where you *have* to revert?**

---

This question was triggered/motivated when I encountered the following error, which I believe is an error in the compiler (but I'd be happy to be corrected).

```
struct X {};

int main() {
  X x;
  X& y{x}; // works with (x)
  X& z{y}; // works with (y)
}
```

Which doesn't compile on g++ 4.7.1 nor does it on [ideone's 4.5.1](http://ideone.com/5da9s).

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:5:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'X&' from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
prog.cpp:6:9: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'X&' from an rvalue of type '<brace-enclosed initializer list>'
```

Note that it works when I replace `X` with `int`.

Comment: The new construction syntax with curly braces is NOT supposed to be a general replacement for all the previous construction syntaxes.  Unfortunately, this is a VERY common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brace initialization works everywhere an initializer is used. There are situations where you have to use parens in order to access a constructor that a brace initializer cannot access, but they are rare.

```
std::vector<int> v(1,1);
std::vector<int> v{1,1};
```

`vector<int>` happens to have a specialized constructor that takes two `int`s and is therefore ambiguous with trying to construct a vector two `int`s long. The ambiguous constructor exists only for backwards compatibility. New classes should not be defined with any constructors that would conflict with an initializer_list.

The ambiguity is resolved by the fact that brace initialization syntax prefers initializer_list constructors over other constructors that would otherwise match. If you want to resolve the ambiguity in favor of using the non-initializer_list constructor then you can't use brace initialization.

---

Bjarne Stroustrup writes

> The uniform use of {} initialization only became possible in C++11, so older C++ code uses () and = initialization. Consequently, the () and = may be more familiar to you. However, I don't know any logical reason to prefer the () notation except in the rare case where you need to distinguish between initialization with a list of elements and a list of constructor arguments.
>   
>                                                          — *The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition* §17.3.2.1

---

Your example code is perfectly legal and should work as expected. The error you're getting is simply a bug in GCC. Clang and VC++ 2012 both accept the code.

Comment: Excellent point. That could have been fixed by defining the second version as `std::vector<int> v{{1,1}};`.

Comment: @bitmask these situations actually aren't that rare, since an initialization list constructor trumps all other constructors. Related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976927/when-to-use-the-brace-enclosed-initializer/9977266#9977266).

Comment: @bitmask I don't think that would be an improvement. All that would do is change the syntax you have to use in order to indicate a preference for initializer_list constructors or not. Basically braces would be exactly equivalent to parens and to use an initializer list in either case would require a nested set of braces, meaning that the syntax would not be uniform with array initialization.

Comment: @bames53: Right, didn't think about arrays.

Comment: In my mind, I use `{}` to initialize from a list of values (including one or zero values), and `()` for all other constructors.  This resolves all ambiguities.

Comment: @MooingDuck That works. I prefer to just always use `{}` and to avoid using or writing constructors that can't be used by brace initialization.