# C++ Class Initialization List example

Tags: c++, class, object, initialization-list

I am going through Chapter 17 in the new Stroustrup book and I am confused by initializing a class with an initialization list.

Example:

in .hpp:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A() : _plantName(std::string s), _growTimeMinutes(int 1);
        virtual ~A();

    private:
        std::string _plantName;
        int _growTimeMinutes;
};
```

in .cpp:

```
A::A() : _plantName(std::string s), _growTimeMinutes(int i)
{

}
```

or is it in .cpp:

```
A::A(std::string s, int i) : _plantName(std::string s), _growTimeMinutes(int i)
{

}
```

and calling that:

```
A a {"Carrot", 10};
```

I learned c++ back in 1998 and have only programmed in it off and on over the years until recently. How long ago did this stuff change? I know I could still do that the older way but I really want to learn new!

Comment: Those were around long before C++11. The brace initialization wasn't.

Comment: Can you please edit this and try to clarify what your actual question is? The various constructor implementations and declarations are all trying to initialize members that don't exist, so it's hard to tell what part you're asking about.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: @chris Brace initialization was introduced in C++03, but only on structs and classes that conform to the Plain Old Data (POD) definition.

Comment: @djf, I was kind of thinking that as I said it. I could have said uniform initialization, but then the OP would have no idea what I'm talking about. I figured it would be unambiguous enough since the POD rule can't apply here.

Comment: @chris yeah, I expected you knew. I just put it out for completeness

Comment: @djf In C++03, brace initialization would require an `=` sign. OP's code sample requires C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza good point, hadn't noticed that

Answer (score 4):

First I think initialization lists are useful when when you are dealing with constant members or when passing objects as parameters since you avoid calling the default constructor then the actual assignement.

You should write the following code in your cpp file : no need to rewrite the parameters types in the initialization list.

```
A::A(std::string s, int i) : _plantName(s), _growTimeMinutes(i)
{
}
```

Your h file should be :

```
class A
{
    public:
         A(std::string, int);
    private:
        std::string _plantName;
        int _growTimeMinutes;
};
```

And you should create a new A object like that

```
A new_object("string", 12);
```

Comment: point of clarification. Stroustrup shows: `double d2 {2.3};` can one not do that for user defined types? thus the way you notated it above?

Comment: I didn't know that notation : it seems you can write both forms and it'll be equivalent in most cases.
You may want to read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976927/when-to-use-the-brace-enclosed-initializer).

Comment: so now what I am learning is that since _plantName and _growTimeMinutes are part of another class that A() extends I need to think about this different yet

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
A::A(std::string s, int i) : _plantName(s), _growTimeMinutes(i) {

}
```

for example

supposing the variables _plantName and _growTimeMinutes are declared within class A or one of its superclasses. s and i are the constructor parameters for class A, the initialization will then call the string-constructor for _plantName with argument s and the int-constructor for _growTimeMinutes with argument i, thus initializing both variables.

Initialization lists are especially needed if you want to initialize const references. The assignment within a constructor would not work.

Hope I could help

Comment: Pedantic, maybe, but it can't call the int constructor because ints don't have one.

Comment: and is the header correct because I read that you dont put it in your  header (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) but i see other examples that do have it in a header too (http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/)

Comment: @chris You're absolutely right. It is not an actual constructor in a technical sense, since int is an integral data type. I used the term for clarification in this case.

Comment: @Jason, You put it in the definition.

Comment: @chris, Thanks. So member initialization is really beneficial as the object ic created after initialization where as is not the case with member assignment. So in theory I can pass functions  and that work is dont first then the object created with the work done. Seems like it could have some speed benefits due to this