# Does the equal sign make a difference in brace initialization? eg. 'T a = {}' vs 'T a{}'

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, list-initialization

Here are two ways to initialize a variable in C++11:

```
T a {something};
T a = {something};
```

I tested these two in all scenarios I could think of and I failed to notice a difference. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9979213/1792401) suggests that there is a subtle difference between the two:

> For variables I don't pay much attention between the `T t = { init };` or `T t { init };` styles, I find the difference to be minor and will at worst only result in a helpful compiler message about misusing an explicit constructor.

So, is there any difference between the two?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is list initialization (using curly braces) better than the alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18222926/why-is-list-initialization-using-curly-braces-better-than-the-alternatives)

Comment: @user202729 I couldn't find an answer there. The accepted answer talks about narrowing restrictions which happen with and without the equals sign.

Comment: ... the question asks for basically the same thing, but because of the different wording, they attracts different kinds of answers. Can't hurt to link it here.

Comment: (that message is the auto-generated for duplicate flag, by the way)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The only significant difference I know is in the treatment of `explicit` constructors:

```
struct foo
{
    explicit foo(int);
};

foo f0 {42};    // OK
foo f1 = {42};  // not allowed
```

This is similar to the "traditional" initialization:

```
foo f0 (42);  // OK
foo f1 = 42;  // not allowed
```

See [over.match.list]/1.

---

Apart from that, there's a defect (see [CWG 1270](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1270)) in C++11 that allows brace-elision only for the form `T a = {something}`

```
struct aggr
{
    int arr[5];
};

aggr a0 = {1,2,3,4,5};  // OK
aggr a1 {1,2,3,4,5};    // not allowed
```

Comment: Doesn't a = {something} also result in an extra copy/move?

Comment: @gvd No, that's where "traditional" copy-init and copy-list-init differ: `foo f0 = 42;` converts `42` to a prvalue temporary `foo` and direct-initializes `f0` with that temporary (via a possibly elided copy/move), whereas `foo f1 = {42};` selects a constructor of `f1` to be called with `42` (the copy+move ctor may be deleted in this case).