# Is there any difference between these two list initialization syntaxes in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider a class with two `std::atomic<int>` members, initialized as below.
I'm looking for a language lawyer answer, with references, to the question: is
there any difference between the two of these syntaxes according to the C++11
standard?

```
class Foo {
  std::atomic<int> a   {17};  // 1.
  std::atomic<int> b = {17};  // 2.
}
```

My reading of [dcl.init] in the standard is that these are both
*list-initialization*, but I'm having trouble keeping all of the relevant bits
in my head and am not confident about that.

If there's no difference for `std::atomic<int>`, would there be for any other
type?

**Edit**: This was marked as a dupe of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733360/does-the-equals-sign-make-a-difference-in-brace-initialization) that does answer the basic issue, but doesn't contain references in the standard. I'm looking for particular sections that define these to be equivalent, or define their differences. In particular, I can't find the exact place where the syntax for #2 is defined.

Comment: `std::atomic<int>` is not different in this regard.

Comment: "but doesn't contain references in the standard" -- dyp's answer there does contain the references you're asking for. It mentions [over.match.list]/1 directly in the answer, and CWG 1270 contains the mention of [dcl.init.aggr]/11.

Comment: Well I can also mention [dcl.init]/17, which says that if the initializer is a *braced-init-list*, it's list-initialization. And that applies to both cases. Edit: Hmm it should probably be *initializer* inclusive-or (*initializer-clause* after `=`).

Comment: Interesting. This seems to be a minor defect in the Standard. [dcl.init]/17 is supposed to catch all initialization with *braced-init-lists*, yet it grammatically only applies to `X x{..}` but not to `X x = {..}`

Comment: @hvd: I missed that, sorry. Thanks!

Comment: @dyp: Yes, this is exactly my confusion. I guess the paragraph starting with "The form of initialization (using parentheses or =) is generally insigniﬁcant" is supposed to cover this, but it's not exactly precise. It also calls out to a section below, but not specifically, so I'm not sure which it means.

Comment: @dyp: I've filed an issue report about this: https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/332