# What is the difference, if any, between {x} and '= {x}' initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand the semantic difference between these two ways of initialization:

```
Foo foo{x};
Foo foo = {x};
```

I am interested to know the difference in the following cases:

1. `x` is of type `Foo`.
2. `Foo` has a constructor that takes an argument of the same type as that of x.
3. `x` is not of type `Foo` but a converting constructor is available.
4. `x` is not of type `Foo` but an `explicit` converting constructor is available.

By difference I mean, in each case:

1. Conceptually, which constructors are invoked?
2. Which constructors calls are usually optimized away by the compiler?
3. Is implicit conversion allowed?

Comment: Have you done any research at all? [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) pretty much covers all there is to know about list initialization.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "explicit converting constructor". And I'm not sure what kind of distinction you are trying to draw between 2) and 3).

Comment: Downvoted because you didn't do any research. A question is only useful if the information does not already exist.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20733360/

Comment: http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Foo foo{x};    // 1

Foo foo = {x}; // 2
```

1 is *direct-list-initialization*. 2 is *copy-list-initialization*.

Assuming that `Foo` is a class type, then in most cases they do exactly the same thing, conceptually or otherwise, except that if an explicit constructor is selected during overload resolution, then #2 is ill-formed. In particular, unlike copy-initialization, copy-list-initialization does not conceptually construct a temporary.

The one exception is when `x` is of type `Foo` or a type derived therefrom. In this case, #1 is equivalent to `Foo foo(x);` (i.e., *direct-initialization*) and #2 is equivalent to `Foo foo = x;` (i.e., *copy-initialization*). The subtle difference is that overload resolution for #2 in this case considers only non-explicit constructors, rather than considering all constructors and then becoming ill-formed if an explicit constructor is selected.* This exception is added by the resolution of [CWG issue 1467](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1467), which was adopted last November.

---

<sub>* You'd have to write some pretty tortured code for this to matter. For example:</sub>

```
struct X
{
    X() = default;
    explicit X(X&);
    X(const X&);
};

int main() { 
    X x1;
    X x2 = {x1}; // #1
    X x3 = x1;   // #2
}
```

<sub>Pre-CWG1467, line #1 is ill-formed because overload resolution selects `X(X&)`, which is `explicit`. Post-CWG1467, the `explicit` constructor `X(X&)` isn't considered, so `X(const X&)` is used. Note that line #2 is always well-formed and uses `X(const X&)`.</sub>

Comment: You may want to improve this answer by quoting the relevant sections from the standard, clarify some parts and so on.

Comment: @black IMO quoting the standard to explain initialization leads to bloat unless it's a language-lawyer esque question. The OP is essentially asking how initialization works, it would be unnecessary.

Comment: @remyabel Well yes but I think the answer should be expanded to cover the topics the OP's asking about a little more completely.

Comment: @black If you read the question, you can see the OP is asking about 4 different cases, with 3 questions for each. I'm unable to see why T.C. should have to jump through hoops to make an unnecessarily bloated answer when what he has so far is sufficient.

Comment: @remyabel Different POVs. Now that the answer has been updated it seems to be more valid. --end OT.]