# What's the difference in instantiating variable with vs. without braces in C++?

Tags: c++, declaration, instantiation, braces

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct CTest 
{
    CTest() { cout << "Constructor called"; }
    CTest(string s) { cout << "Any constructor with parameters"; } 
};

int main () {
  CTest t1;
  CTest t2{};
}
```

I come from the Java world and there `t1` would just have been declared which definitely isn't the case here since both both lines call the constructor of `CTtest`. In this case, t1 calls the overwritten default constructor as well as t2. Are there any cases where it actually makes a difference or can we always omit the braces?

Maybe it's just me, but I couldn't find any hint on that. There are only discussions about when to use braces vs. parentheses (vs. value vs. copy constructor).

Comment: Parenthesis refers to `()`.  Braces refers to `{}`.  Brackets refers to `[]`. I don't see you using parenthesis anywhere...

Comment: Those are braces, and I'm sure it's on here somewhere, but value-initialization vs. default-initialization.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9976927/183120) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18222926/183120) are dupes for brace initialization, pick one :)

Comment: There are quite a few subtly different types of initialization in C++, which can be confusing to someone new to the language.  [This article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1852519) provides a good overview.

Comment: @bcrist, I don't like that they use the term "default initialization" to mean value-initialization because there's already a specific default-initialization, and that doesn't do it.

Comment: @anorton, I've grown up with brackets meaning () and the term "parentheses" not used much. We say "square brackets" for [], and I see/hear curly braces/brackets for {} often enough, but I prefer just braces.

Comment: @chris hmm, you're right; they're saying `x{}` is default initialization, which it is not... I skimmed that part when I read it the first time, guess I should have read it closer.

Comment: @bcrist, I think it's a made up term. They describe it as value-initialization, but don't use the proper term. The main problem is that the term they do use only differs from a completely different type of initialization by a hyphen.

Comment: My question seems to have been misunderstood, so I edited it. To make it clear: I'm aware of the topics about when it's best to use braces or parentheses. I just want to know if there is a difference if we just leave the braces away. (if it doesn't make a difference here but in another example, I'd be interested in it too)

Answer (score 0):

When the only constructor for a class is its default constructor then doing initialization with curly braces doesn't matter:

```
CTest t1;
CTest t2{};
```

Are the same.

Its only once you have other constructors that take parameters that putting values for those parameters inside of `{}` that you are doing something new.

Comment: Sorry to say, but they aren't. A defaulted or deleted default constructor will cause zero-initialization. Default-initialization is then done afterward if that constructor is non-trivial.

Comment: Keep in mind there is a difference between the "trivial" default constructor and a user-provided one.

Comment: @JesseGood, And even a non-user-provided one can be non-trivial. Consider a class containing a member with a non-trivial default constructor (full list in § 12.1 /5).