# C++11: string(50, 'x') versus string{50, 'x'}

Tags: c++11, constructor, undefined-behavior, initializer

As seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/VIBlPE):

```
cout << string(50, 'x'); // xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
cout << string{50, 'x'}; // 2x
```

WAT??

I have figured out that 50 is ASCII '2', so:

```
cout << static_cast<int>('2'); // 50
cout << static_cast<char>(50); // 2
```

But that's as far as I've got.

Does this lead to a solid argument against C++11 initializers?

Comment: the `initializer_list` constructor of `string` takes a list of characters, that's why.

Comment: ([here's the relevant documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string))

Comment: To answer the last line: No, it doesn't. It just means you have to understand what they do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do `string { 50, 'x' }` you're essentially initializing the string with a list of characters.

On the other hand, `string(50, 'x')` calls a 2 argument constructor, which is defined to repeat the character `x` 50 times. The reason why `string { 50, 'x' }` doesn't pick the constructor is that it could be ambiguous. What if you had a three parameter constructor as well? If the type has an `initializer_list` constructor, it will be picked when you use `{ ... }` for initialization.

Basically you need to be aware of the constructors your type has. The `initializer_list` constructor will always have a precedence to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Shouldn't `{50, 'x'}` not be convertible to `std::initializer_list<char>` due to the narrowing conversion?