# When should we use parenthesis ( ) vs. initializer { } syntax to initialize objects in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, c++14

**Updated**

I have gone through links (such as [When to use the brace-enclosed initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976927/when-to-use-the-brace-enclosed-initializer)) on when should I use use `{}` brace initialization, but information is not given on when we should use parenthesis `( )` vs. initializer `{ }` syntax to initialize objects in C++11/14? What standard practices suggest to use `()` over `{}`?

In rare cases, such as `vector<int> v(10,20);` or `auto v = vector<int>(10,20);`, the result is a `std::vector` with 10 elements. If we uses braces, the result is a `std::vector` with 2 elements. But it depends on the caller use case: either he/she want to allocate vector of 10 elements or 2 elements?

Comment: Use `()` when you want to call a constructor.

Comment: @alcedine You can also use `{}` when you want to call a constructor. In that respect, `()` vs. `{}` makes no difference.

Comment: @juanchopanza so it seems! I did not know that.

Comment: @juanchopanza i think it is not duplicate that question have highlighted, when to use {} instead of When should we use parenthesis ( )

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Scott Meyers tackles this issue in Item 7 of his fantastic "Effective Modern C++". He runs through the differences, pros and cons of both syntaxes, and concludes

> There’s no consensus that either approach is better than the other, so my advice is to pick one and apply it consistently.

On the other hand, the C++ Core Guidelines suggest that you [prefer the initialiser syntax](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es23-prefer-the--initializer-syntax), so perhaps that's the better default to go for.

Comment: Personally I tend to agree with Meyers on this one, but I also have to write code in many cases that has to build with older versions of Visual C++ that lack support for {} initializer lists. Like ``auto``, it's more often than not a matter of judgement where it improves vs. obscures readability. Still, if you are entirely new to C++, you are probably safer with the rules for {} initializers per the core guidelines.

Answer (score 11):

Congratulations, you've just hit on the canonical example of why you should prefer braced initialization if your compiler supports.

If you want a `std::vector` of two elements, you use:

```
vector<int> v = { 10, 20 };
```

If you use `vector<int> v(10,20);` you are actually calling the constructor that takes two integer-convertible elements which is the signature `explicit vector  (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());` Remember that `std::vector` was added to the language in C++98 while braced-initialization didn't get added until C++11.

See the [Core C++ Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md), specifically [ES.23: Prefer the  {}  initializer syntax](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-list)

Comment: Any why is this an example of why one should *prefer* one over the other? To me, it looks more like an example where you don't actually have a choice.

Comment: This is covered in a lot of details by Herb Sutter and Bjarne Stroustrup in the link to the Core C++ Guidelines.