# C++11 uniform initialization: ambiguity between initializer list and multiple-parameter constructors?

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently trying to wrap my head around C++11's uniform initialization. I came upon this ambiguous case: consider a class which can either be constructed from either a two-argument constructor or an initializer list of any length:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(int a, int b) {
      std::cout << "constructor 1" << std::endl;
    }
    Foo(std::initializer_list<int>) {
      std::cout << "constructor 2" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Following uniform initialization convention, I'd expect the following to work:

`Foo a (1, 2)` prints `constructor 1` (duh)

`Foo b {1, 2}` prints `constructor 1`

`Foo c = {1, 2}` prints `constructor 2`

However, it seems like the compiler interprets `Foo b {1, 2}` as a list initialization, and calls constructor 2. Is the `()` syntax the only way to force the compiler to consider other kinds of constructors when an initializer-list constructor is present?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976927/when-to-use-the-brace-enclosed-initializer -- std::vector is a "classical example", although I can find little mention of it on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems like the compiler interprets Foo b {1, 2} as a list
> initialization, and calls constructor 2. Is the () syntax the only way
> to force the compiler to consider other kinds of constructors when an
> initializer-list constructor is present?

Quotes from standard draft explains this well:

[9.4.5.2 [dcl.init.list]](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#2) (emphasis mine):

> A constructor is an initializer-list constructor if its first
> parameter is of type std​::​initializer_­list or reference to cv
> std​::​initializer_­list for some type E, and either there are no
> other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments
> ([dcl.fct.default]).

> [Note 2: ***Initializer-list constructors are
> favored*** over other constructors in list-initialization
> ([over.match.list]). Passing an initializer list as the argument to
> the constructor template template C(T) of a class C does not
> create an initializer-list constructor, because an initializer list
> argument causes the corresponding parameter to be a non-deduced
> context ([temp.deduct.call]). — end note]

and [12.4.2.8 [over.match.list]](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list#1):

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such
> that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed
> according to the rules in this subclause or when forming a
> list-initialization sequence according to [over.ics.list], overload
> resolution selects the constructor in two phases:

- > If the initializer list is not empty or T has no default constructor,
  > ***overload resolution is first performed where the candidate functions
  > are the initializer-list constructors*** ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T
  > and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single
  > argument.
- > Otherwise, or ***if no viable initializer-list constructor is found***,
  > overload resolution is performed **again**, where the ***candidate functions
  > are all the constructors of the class T*** and the argument list consists
  > of the elements of the initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra ignored argument to your constructor to specify a particular overload at callsite, like they do in STL:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct non_init_list_t {};
inline constexpr non_init_list_t non_init_list;

struct Class {
    Class(int a, int b, non_init_list_t = non_init_list) { std::clog << "()\n"; }
    Class(std::initializer_list<int> list) { std::clog << "{}\n"; }
};

Class a{12, 42, non_init_list};  // ()
Class b{12, 42};                 // {}
Class c(12, 42);                 // ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the constructor has the `initializer_list` version, the compiler will first interpret it as `initializer_list`, if there is no `initializer_list` version, the compiler will interpret it as another overloaded version.
If the compiler interprets it as another version, and you want to call a constructor that uses the `initializer_list` version, it happens that the number and type of arguments are the same as other ctors, then your will cause a bug. Then the compiler chooses the `initializer_list` version or other version? So using bracket notation is definitely not the `initializer_list` version. If you don't have an `initializer_list` version in your constructor, don't worry about this issue.

BTW, if you use `auto` to infer type automatically, DO NOT use uniform initialization. It must interpret type to `initializer_list`.